# Pip install numpy throws "not supported" error. But I swear I have the right version

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm baffled.  Here's a screenshot of my PC specs:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of me trying to pip install numpy. I have Python 2.7.  Am I missing something here?

[image]

I got the install files from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy.
The .whl files are in the C:\Python27 directory.  Please help!

Comment: type `python` in the CMD Prompt, does it say 32bit or 64bit? Make sure you're on 64bit python too.

Comment: Aha! You nailed it.  I did "import struct; print struct.calcsize("P") * 8".  I have 32 bit python.  Thank you for helping me.  I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got the wrong version of Python 2.7 installed. You can confirm this by typing `python` in the CMD Prompt, `WinKey+R` then `python`.

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)
```

If it says 4, it's 32bit or, 8 for 64bit, you'll want to make sure you're installing the correct version of the library. In your case it sounds like you're looking for Python 2.7 64bit.